# Uber Wheelchair option hide request

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have integrated uber api in one of my application as per specify in uber documentation.But client has open that application in US region they saw uber wheelchair as default ride and they won't be able to change it.I want to know is there any option where we can remove those option from that region or i have to write any code for that?

Your help will be really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

First step :

Fetch all products associated to that location using below uberSDK method.Check response and filter respective product which your client want to set.There are multiple product response given by the UBER SDK as per region or location.

```
ridesClient.fetchProducts(pickupLocation: pickupLocation) { (products, response) in
        for (i,element) in products.enumerate()
        {
           if element.name == "uberX"
           {
            builder = builder.setProductID(element.productID!)
            button.rideParameters = builder.build()
            button.loadRideInformation()
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the product name returned from the API and filter the products available.